How to use spray foam overhead if the can needs to be upside down?
I have a remote Ontario cabin that is raised off the ground on wood beams and cinder blocks.
I want to use cans of spray foam such as GREAT STUFF Large Gap Filler Insulating Foam Sealant - 340 g to seal gaps between the 8-inch polystyrene insulation and the floor joists. I would do this by crawling on the ground under the floor and spraying the foam upwards.
However, it’s my limited understanding that spray foam cans need to be sprayed with the straw pointing down and the can would be upside down. If that’s the case, then how can I spray upwards?

When I look closer at the product description for the Great Stuff foam, it says:

All-direction, no-drip dispensing eliminates messes

So it appears that some spray foam products don’t need to be sprayed upside down.

Usually the can does not need to point vertically upwards. You can use it sideways, as long as the nozzle is mostly pointing downwards.
If the job is larger than couple feet, I strongly recommend a foam gun - your hands will thank you after the job. The foam gun has added benefit of having internal capacity, so it can work upside down for a bit before needing to be turned right way up to refill internally. It is also way easier to operate in cramped spaces.
Do buy at least one more can than you think you need - things happen, and most shops will accept returns of unopened, untampered cans.
Oh, and do wear basic eye protection. The foam is nasty and hard to get off when it sticks to your skin and you surely don't want it in your eyes.

You can replace the "straw" with a longer tube of suitable size if your foam can or foam gun is direction sensitive, allowing you to hold the can as needed and dispense foam wherever needed.
